# Using Memcached with YII's Query Builder

Tags: memcached, yii

I'm using  [YII's Query builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) for SELECT queries in my application. How to use memcached along with the same?

Regards,
Abhijit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In config:

```
    ......
'components'=>array(
    ......
    'cache'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.caching.CMemCache',
        'servers'=>array(
            array('host'=>'server1', 'port'=>11211, 'weight'=>60),
        ),
    ),
),
);
```

And with queries something like this:

```
$rows = Yii::app()->db->cache(1000, $dependency)->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

or for ActiveRecord:

```
$posts = Post::model()->with('comments')->findAll();
```

There is a good tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.overview